# Is there a way I can make my search results list only show one result at a time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm setting up a list of items and I have a search bar which is made in Javascript that shows items that have the given characters I enter into the search bar.

```js
function example2() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("example");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("example5");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="example" onkeyup="example2()" placeholder="Search.." title="example">

<ul id="example5">
    <li><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I am trying to do is, When the page loads all the list items are hidden. Then when I search it shows 1 result only and not multiple with the item visible.

For example, list item 1 is "table", list item 2 is "chair" and list item 3 is "water". On page load, these items will all be hidden. When I type a letter into the search bar, only one result is shown at a time.

Edit: Sorry I forgot to add, say if you type in "item" I would like it to only show 1 result, making you have to search roughly the exact term. Instead of showing all items.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Why not just add a style display:none then when your function get trigger change it to display:block

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var li_count = 0;
function example2() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("example");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("example5");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
            li_count++;
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        // Limit the displayed li
        if(li_count == 1) {
          break;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a style display to `ul` and then change it when you are calling your function.

```js
function example2() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("example");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("example5");
    ul.style.display = "block";
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="example" onkeyup="example2()" placeholder="Search.." title="example">

<ul id="example5" style="display:none">
    <li><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up the approach a little.

```js
var input, filter, ul, lis, a, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById("example");
ul = document.getElementById("example5");
lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
function example2() {
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        var li = lis[i];
        txtValue = li.getAttribute("data-val");
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            li.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="example" onkeyup="example2()" placeholder="Search.." title="example">

<ul id="example5">
    <li data-val="list item 1"  style="display:none"><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 1</a></li>
    <li data-val="list item 2"  style="display:none"><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 2</a></li>
    <li data-val="list item 3"  style="display:none"><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 3</a></li>
    <li data-val="list item 4"  style="display:none"><a class="#" href="#" data-modal-id="#">list item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```